# Having trouble assing ax object around with seaborn plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm having trouble getting something like this to work:

```
def make_plots(data, ax):
    sns.lineplot(data,..., ax=ax)
    sns.scatterplot(data, ...., ax=ax)
    return ???

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(5):
    make_plot(data[i], ax)
plt.savefig("all5runs.png")
```

So I have a function that plots a lineplot and scatterplot, hopefully on the same axis. I'd like to keep all 5 runs through the data plotted on one figure, and then save the figure. I'm note sure what `make_plots()` should return, or if I'm passing around the figure data correctly. How can I make this work?

Edit: Currently, I'm just getting a blank canvas in `all5runs.png`

Comment: *I'm not sure what `make_plots()` should return* Well, what do you need? Is your current approach not working? If it's not working, what's happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need something like this: Since `ax` is defined with a global scope, and is passed to the function as an argument, the changes will be updated during each for loop call

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

def make_plots(x, y, ax):
    sns.lineplot(x, y, ax=ax)
    sns.scatterplot(x, y, ax=ax)
    return 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(5):
    x = np.arange(5)
    make_plots(x, x*(i+1), ax)
# plt.show() # Uncomment for showing the figure
plt.savefig('all5runs.png')
```

[image]

Comment: How do you actually display/save the figure at the end?

Comment: @theQman : Check my edit. Try it out and let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you. I'm curious about your comment about 'ax' being global. If I had an 'ax1' and 'ax2' being worked on simultaneously, how would I go about saveing/displaying the relevant ones?

Comment: @theQman : Please explain the ax1, ax2 thing in your question what you mean by that

Comment: @theQman : For the comment on global scope, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)